# Undefined reference: autoref points to section instead of figure or table

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing

Here is a minimum working example

(an image 'test.png' needs to be in the working directory. I used [this one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/test.png).)

```
% Created 2011-05-23 Mon 15:21
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{figure test}
autoref test \autoref{fig:fig1}. 

ref test \ref{fig:fig1}

\begin{figure}[hb]
\caption{test figure}
  \label{fig:fig1}
  \includegraphics[width=1in]{test.png}
\end{figure}



\section{table test}

autoref test \autoref{tab:tab1}. 

ref test \ref{tab:tab1}

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table}
\label{tab:tab1}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is a snapshot of the output that I get:

[image]

### Questions:

How can I get the references to work?

*Note:* In my document, I am finding that the `\autoref{fig:figurename}` gives output as "item 1" instead of "figure 1". When making the MWE, the problems have changed, but I am still confused.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*(This answer refers to the [original code in the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/19150/1).)*

The table reference isn't working because you are referencing `tab:fig1`, while the label is named `tab:tab1`.

The references are pointing to the section, because there is no caption (and hence no number) in your `figure`/`table` environment. Always have the `\label` after `\caption`.

Comment: I fixed the table reference and added a caption, but I am still getting a reference to the section.

Comment: @David: Your code works for me (after compiling twice).

Comment: The new code is working here too. As Caramdir said, compile it twice.

Comment: thanks for the help. Works after compiling twice here as well. Putting the `\label` after the `\caption` solved my problem in the actual document as well.

Comment: For anyone else that comes here; the label needs to come after the caption without any command between label and caption. I had an \end{center} between my caption and label, which caused this same issue.

Answer (score 5):

### Minimal example of using autoref for a figure:

If your autorefs are showing with questionmarks or are linking to the incorrect figures/equations, you have to flush and reset the *.aux files and recompile twice.  Maybe it's a bug in how the autorefs are resolved.  This code demonstrates autorefs correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\begin{document}
\section{Skipper}

Crazy woman gaining!  See \autoref{fig:CrazyWomanGaining}.
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=160pt]{crazy_woman_gaining.png}
  \caption{Chantel DuBois is gaining.}
  \label{fig:CrazyWomanGaining}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\flushleft{Kowalski!  Intel!  Sir, we have a serious problem.}

\autoref{fig:OmegaThreeSlick}.  Petal to the metal private!

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \textcolor{black}{\fboxrule=1pt\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
      \frame{\includegraphics[width=175pt]{omega_three_slick.png}}
      \caption{Our Omega 3 slick will take them down.}
      \label{fig:OmegaThreeSlick}
    \end{minipage}
  }}
\end{figure}

We need more power!  Kowalski!  Fire up the Nuclear reactor!
\end{document}
```

After I compile this and run, I get:

[image]

Note the use of `\autoref{fig:CrazyWomanGaining}` is converted to the string: "Figure 1", and `\autoref{fig:OmegaThreeSlick}` is converted to the string "Figure 2".

Comment: I don't know why the minipages and the flushs and the textcolor, you will get an upvote anyway.

Comment: Apart from penguins, i am not sure what quality this answer really adds.

Comment: I come to stackoverflow for plug and play copy paste answers like this one.  When my code doesn't work right because of bugs in `\autoref`, I want something plug and play that will work that I can fiddle around with.  The code in the original question and the most upvoted answer doesn't have that.