# \autoref for figures uses "section" instead of "figure" as text

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, htlatex

My problem looks very similar to the problem in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19150/37967), and is exactly the same as the problem described [on another forum](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=76792898). But none of those seem to have solved the problem.

When I use the `autoref` command to point to a figure in combination with `htlatex`, the link to the figure is correctly made but the text of the link states "section xxx" instead of "figure xxx".

The problem can be reproduced with the following code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{first_section}
\lipsum
\section{Second section}\label{second_section}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{My invisible figure}
  \label{invisible_figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum

Reference to the figure \autoref{invisible_figure}
\end{document}
```

Running the above code with the `latex` command works as expected. However, when running it with `htlatex`, the following html is generated

```
Reference to the figure <a href="#x1-20011">section&#x00A0;1</a>
```

I expected

```
Reference to the figure <a href="#x1-20011">figure&#x00A0;1</a>
```

instead.

The Lorum ipsum text is added to illustrate that the link points indeed to the figure environment, and not to the section.

This was with the packaged TexLive distribution of Ubuntu 14.04LTS (which is a rather old distribution, I admit).

Comment: I've got correct result with TL 2015. I am sure that `\autoref` behavior was fixed some time ago, your TL doesn't contain the fix

Comment: Good to know. I will have to update my distribution manually then

Comment: TL included in distributions is often quite obsolete, unfortunately. It is best to use TL directly from CTAN.